# How to Hide Title on BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: dart, flutter

Hello everyone is it possible to hide title on bottomNavigationBarItem?

My current setup is as following:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
   iconSize: 30.0,
   type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
   currentIndex: 0,
    items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text(""),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            title: new Text("",),
        )
    ],
),
```

Ofcourse it didn't show the title, But the icon isn't centered.

Comment: In  BottomNavigationBarItem Icon and title are required and they will be placed at their respective position as given in it's class   BottomNavigationBarItem({
   required this.icon,
   required this.title,
    this.backgroundColor,
  })

Comment: @Zulfiqar yes, i'm aware of that, i just need another workaround to hide the title, or reposition the icon, but couldn't find any solution yet